# Why does flask-admin require a ListField of mongoengine to have a field type?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I am trying to use flask-admin, which seems great and easy, but I have a problem.

I have a field in a collection which is defined as a `ListField()`, with an implicit type of `None` for the list field type. The reason I am not defining a type for the field, is because I am keeping a list of lists, and there is no other elegant way (that I found) to accomplish this with mongoengine.

But flask-admin won't let me define such a field, with an error of `ListField "movements" must have field specified for model`.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Any chance you could paste some of your code and show us the version you're using on mongoengine?

Comment: What about a db.ListField(field=db.ListField())

Answer (score 1):

The reason flask admin needs a field specified is because otherwise the form rendering does not know which type of input to display for it.

For example if it is a choice field, date field, or another list field itself !

You could do something like this:

```
my_field = db.ListField(field=db.ListField(field=db.StringField()))
```

The innermost field can be anything, including a EmbeddedDocumentField or IntField, etc.

Also, if you want to continue using `ListField` without specifying the field type, you can also ask flask-admin to just treat this as a string by overriding the `ModelView` and it will then just give you a text box containing the string:

```
[ 'a value', 42, { 'A':'B' } ]
```

So this retains flexibility but reduces structure and makes the validation bad.

Comment: Overiding the ModelView  ( ...  `form_overrides = {'movements': StringField}` ... ) is a nice workaround